# How do I use the Aggregate function to take a list of strings and output a single string separated by a space?

Tags: c#, list, aggregate, tostring

[image]

Here is the source code for this test:

```
    var tags = new List<string> {"Portland", "Code","StackExcahnge" };
    const string separator = " ";
    tagString = tags.Aggregate(t => , separator);
    Console.WriteLine(tagString);
    // Expecting to see "Portland Code StackExchange"
    Console.ReadKey();
```

---

*Update*

Here is the solution I am now using:

```
var tagString = string.Join(separator, tags.ToArray());
```

Turns out `string.Join` does what I need.

Comment: @Brian I actually did paste the source under the image (probably just hard to tell where the image stops and text starts).

Comment: Sorry about that. I couldn't grab the source from your question, so I assumed both were pictures. Please disregard my comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that you can just use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx).

Comment: O ya, forgot about Join. I think that is really what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
string result = tags.Aggregate((acc, s) => acc + separator + s);
```

or simply

```
string result = string.Join(separator, tags);
```

Answer (score 0):

[String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) Method may be?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use

```
public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> strings, string seperator)
{
    return string.Join(seperator, strings.ToArray());
}
```

And then it looks like this

```
tagString = tags.Join(" ")
```